# How to know which Laravel version is currently running without composer.json

Tags: php, laravel

I have updated my **PHP version to 7.2** and changed the **Laravel version** in the `composer.json` file to `5.7.*`

I then ran `composer update` in the console and want to make sure that Laravel updated (I didn't see the outcome of the command since I sent the request to my hosting team)

Is there a way to know for sure which version is running?

Comment: Check ```composer.lock```

Comment: "name": "laravel/framework",
            "version": "v5.0.35",
this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) **Using terminal.**

`php artisan --version` or `php artisan -V`

2) **Using in Files go to** `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php`

[image]

3) **Using the blade template.**

```
{{ App::VERSION() }}
```

4) **Using composer.json**

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
    }
```

5) **Using route.php file**

```
Route::get('laravel-version', function()
{
    $laravel = app();
    echo "Your Laravel version is ".$laravel::VERSION;
});
```

Check with url `yourdomain.com/laravel-version`

Comment: Where can i find route.php?

Comment: Or should I create it and add it to the root?

Comment: And this it seems the laravel version is not 5.7., what did I do wrong in the update process I described?

Comment: Yes, you have to add the code of method 5. then you may `yourdomain.com/laravel-version` and it'll show you on browser.

Comment: Check   SO description to upgrade your version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52849408/upgrading-laravel-5-4-to-latest-version-5-7 or https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade

Answer (score 0):

You can View current Laravel version through Blade Templates

First way:

```
{{ App::VERSION() }}
```

Second way:

```
<?php
     echo $app::VERSION;
?>
```

---

Also, the Laravel version installed can be checked in the command line:

```
php artisan --version
```

This will show you which Laravel version is currently running.